# Prove by induction $7^n$ is an odd number for every natural number n

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

I have proved the base case already of n=1 where $7 = 2p+1$

Then I assumed $n=k$ for $7^k = 2p+1$ for $k \in N$ and  $p \in N$

To prove $7^{k+1} = 2p+1$  I have these steps so far:

$7(7^k) = 2p+1$

$7(2p+1) = 2p+1$

$14p+7 = 2p+1$

I am not sure how to prove from here.

Comment: I feel that you are rather overcomplicating things. You know that $7$ is odd. You presumably know that the product of two odd numbers is odd. That gives you your induction step in one line.

Comment: You are confused about writing the odd numbers. If you have an odd number $2p+1$, another odd number is not necessarily $2p+1$ (same number), it can be $2q+1$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just rewrite your sum as

$$14p+7=2(7p+3)+1$$

Also, it's not a good idea to use $p$ for all of your steps.  If $7^k=2p+1$, then you need to show that $7^{k+1}=2q+1$ for some integer $q$.  Otherwise the equality is not actually equal since you are using the same expression as your desired form for different valued expressions.
Now since $14p+7=2(7p+3)+1$, let $q=7p+3$.  Thus $7^{k+1}=2q+1$. And you're done.

Answer (score 3):

If $7^k$ is odd i.e. $7^k=2p+1$ for some integer $p$, then
$$
7^{k+1}=7(2p+1)=14p+7=2(7p+3)+1
$$
as desired.

Answer (score 2):

More simply: take as given that the product of two odd numbers is odd and that 7 is odd.

Suppose $7^k$ is odd. Then $7^{k+1} = 7^k × 7$ is the product of two odd numbers and therefore also odd.

i.e.: If the proposition is true for $n=k$, it is also true for $n=k+1$.

But it is true for $n=1$, since $7^1=7$ is odd. Therefore by induction it is true for all $n>0$.

(I'm assuming this is an exercise in understanding proof by induction, not in understanding odd numbers.)

Comment: In fact it's also true for $n=0$ since $7^0=1$, and I wondered about using that as the base case, but that's only valid if we've defined the natural numbers as including $0$.